# Updating minimum order quantity (Front End View)

Tags: magento-1.9, product, orders, frontend, quantity

I am trying to change the 'Minimum order quantity' on the front end because it currently displays '0'.

[image: Minimum Order Quantity - Example]

All simple and configurable products currently display 0. I have gone into the attributes of each product in the admin dashboard and tried changing it that way. What i changed was:

*Catalogue -> Manage Products -> (Product 1 - Edit Attribute) -> Inventory > Changing 'Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Basket' to 1.*

However this does not solve the problem and update the minimum order quantity on the front end.

How can i fix this so it displays '1' on the front end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your question mention you want to show `minimum order quantity`.

Goto `app\design\frontend\<Your Theme>\default\template\catalog\product\view.phtml`

before quantity section add this code

```
<?php 
$productQuantity = Mage::getModel("cataloginventory/stock_item")->loadByProduct($_product->getId()); 
$min_no_order = $productQuantity->getMinSaleQty(); 
echo $min_no_order;
?>
```

I hope this will help you...!

Comment: Thank you very much. Solved my problem. I realised it was BSS that was overriding the original setting but your code fixes this. Thanks.

Comment: @PeterSmith: welcome :)